# How to hide MySQL connection information in PHP?

Tags: php

Im using a mysql database to store user infromation and I'm worried that someone will look at the source code by inspect element or something like that and see my connection password. Is there any way to encrypt this or hide it?

For example:
`$ con = mysqli_connect(blah, blah, password_i_want_to_hide, blah);`

Comment: *"will look at the source code by inspect element"* You know that the PHP code is not sent to the browser, right?

Comment: Inspect element is a client side action within the browser. It has nothing to do with server side variables.

Answer (score 1):

You can store MySQL Connection Details in a separate configuration file outside of the web root directory.

Create a configuration file `config.php` and place it outside the web root. In config.php file define your MySQL Connection details.

Include it in your main PHP file:

```
<?php
include_once('../config.php');  // Adjust the path accordingly
$conn = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
```

Make sure that configuration file is outside the web root